IIS is not correctly picking up the root
I have a asp,net core app and it was hosted in a windows server.
in there https://test.com/
popup the IIS screen
https://test.com/home
shows home page correctly
This was working fine until yesterday. I cannot find the issue.
My Default document put like below

Here is how I put routes
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

Restarted the PC, Restarted the IIS. Nothing working

If everything was working fine until yesterday as you said then check your event viewer on your windows server, the problem isn't from your application.

Do you remember whether you have modified rewrite rules or inbound/outbound rules recently? If there is no changes in IIS, please check the windows update history first. If the new patch was installed, you can uninstall it for testing.

If the steps above not work for you, we have to enable the Failed Request Tracing Rules to check more details.
